# Implementing Sharekit from a button instead of a toolbar

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, uiactionsheet, sharekit

I am new to both sharekit and ios development. Would like to have some help in implementing sharekit from a button instead of a toolbar..

For example, I sharing an link:

```
- (IBAction) btnShareClicked :(id)sender;
{
    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:webView.request.URL title:[webView pageTitle]];
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

How do change this example code to include the button instead of a toolbar.. Need some guidance.. Sorry if it is a stupid question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction) btnShareClicked :(id)sender;
{
     NSString *text = @"Hello";

    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:text];
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];  
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check the `UIActionSheet` documentation...

e.g.

```
[actionSheet showInView:[sender view];
```

or:

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:[[sender view] frame] inView:[[sender view] superview] animated:YES];
```

assuming that the sender is your button, which it should be.